# How to sort the grid view in a modal popup without changing the url in YII2?

Tags: php, yii2, yii-components

I have a gridview inside the modal popup.  I tried to sort the grid view columns inside the model popup. i tried with Pjax but it changes the page url.
I want to sort gridview in the modal popup without changing the url.
Code:

```
     <?php  \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin();
             echo GridView::widget([
                 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                 'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                 'id' => 'data_lines_tables',
                 'columns' => [
                          [
                           'name',
                            'id'
                           ]
                         ]
                  ]);
            \yii\widgets\Pjax::end();?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Pjax will use [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) to update url, you should simply disable this by using :

```
\yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false]);
```

Read more about [Pjax widget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html).

Comment: I have resolved my issue, its because i didnt gave unique id to PJAX. \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false,'id' =>'UniQueiD']);
so sorting results are displayed in the modal itself

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are two ways to do sorting for Cgridview in Modal popup, I have tried in bootstrap modal popup.

1. Try using the CSort. Please remember, they keys in in `$sort->attributes` should match columns in the CGridView:

   ```
   public function actionIndex(){
   $sort = new CSort();
   $sort->attributes = array(
   'employee'=>array(
     'asc'=>'employee.name',
     'desc'=>'employee.name desc',
   ),
   'company'=>array(
     'asc'=>'company.company_name',
     'desc'=>'company.company_name desc',
   ),
   );

   $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('job', array(
    'criteria'=>array('Criteria goes here'),
    'sort'=>$sort,
   ));
   $this->render('index',array(
   'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
   ));
   ```
2. You can also use the sort like this, if u want to sort according to time or id whatever you choose according to your fields in database.

   ```
   $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('job', array(
       'criteria'=>array('Criteria goes here'),
       'sort'=>array(
           'defaultOrder'=>'createTime DESC',
           ),
    ));
   ```

Comment: i have tried Sort instead of CSort for yii2.. But sorting results are displayed in the background page instead of displaying in bootstrap modal..?

Comment: I havenot tried in yii2, im only vision yii1.1 and it is working for me.